# page editing by the client without an editor

Tags: html, editing

How to do it so that the customer can edit his website in a simple way, without having to enter the html code, so that he can add a photo or a file through the website instead of going to the editor. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use your favorite search engine to look for "content management system", also known as CMS.

There are some ready-to-use hosted solutions (e.g. blogger.com); there are also software packages you can run on your own server (e.g. WordPress). Depending on your needs, you might also want to consider a Wiki system, where only approved users have editing rights.